# Openid and RestFul API

Tags: rest, api, openid, steam

My website have a Restful API, with authentication needed. When a user log-in in website, it's performed a HTTP Basic authentication (username and password), and is returned a access token generated in API.

But recently I have implemented steam login (Yeah, steam can act as an OpenID provider). Everything okay, but How can I auth the user on the API, if no password is sended.

Comment: How about OAuth2 Bearer tokens?

Comment: @Evert I don't know what this means, sorry :c

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't really help you.

Comment: @IanOn what programming language are you using?

Comment: @BrunoPeres PHP, but i think that not change

Comment: Depending on the strategy you use is the action you will take... Previously you use HTTP Basic authentication, that's why you redirect to login page whenever the user is not authenticated. Now, you are changing your strategy to OpenId kind of... So you don't have to generate the token anymore as the Steam API will provide the token for you. You have to use this new token in place of the one you used to generate and grant the user access accordingly. For that, you need to better understand how the JWT works.

Comment: Okay. I've create a flow with this sequence: First user is redirect to steam's openid url, user provides credentials, if correct: steam redirect to /api/login, the parameters is verified and if correct will be redirected to website with a jwt token.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an username and / or password to authenticate an user that login into your site using an OpenId provider (Steam, in your case). What you need is **to trust** in this OpenId Provider.

This is a very good definition about OpenId by John Christopher Jones in a blog post:

> *OpenID* is an authentication strategy where an unauthenticated user
>   visits your site then authenticates themselves by logging in to
>   Google, Twitter, Facebook, Steam, or some other *OpenID provider*. Your
>   server (the *OpenID Relying Party*) exchanges keys with the *OpenID*
>   *Provider* (Google, et. al.) then sends the user over to the *OpenID*
>   *Provider* to log in.
>
> After the user logs in with the *OpenID Provider*, **the user is sent back**
>   **to you with some information identifying who they are**, signed by the
>   key you exchanged with the *OpenID Provider*. **You can trust their**
>   **identity at this point and start "logging them in" to your own system**
>   **based on their identity**.

The image bellow shows the OpenId Flow:

[image: OpenId Flow]

As you can see, after verify credentials, the OpenId Provider (Steam) will send back the user to your website, including credentials in the URL. With these credentials in hands what you need to do is:

1. Verify if a user associated with this credentials already exists in the
   database. If not, create it.
2. Create a API token associated with this user.
3. Send the API token for the user waiting on the browser (your client app that consumes your RESTful API).

With this API token in hands your client application can add these token to every request to your RESTful API, as the same way that an authenticated user with username and password would do. Note that your token generation strategy can not be dependent of a username and password.

Comment: Well..Then the OpenID provider should return to my RestFul API login action and if the verification is successful, redirects to my website with the access token?

Comment: Not exactly. Your RESTful API login action has no relation with the OpenID auth flow. After the user auths successfully in the OpenID provider the flow will return to an URL (or action) **indicated by you** in the configuration of your OpenID client library. Inside this action you should follow the 3 steps indicated in this answer. I suggest you to see [this example](https://codepen.io/johnchristopherjones/post/setting-up-openid) of OpenID with Steam.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you want to make sure that the user is authenticated. Here Steam provides your server with a key (OpenID server) and your server has provided a key to the OpenID server. This is very similar to tokens used for Anti-Forgery attacks. Steam provides your server with the user's identification and your server notes down Steam server's location. Then the user is allowed to view your server`s content. Steam surely uses an API so if credentials are cached in the browser well it won't ask for them in the future.

Note: HTTP is stateless so you have to use sessions to make sure that a user`s is still logged on.